# How does ColorInvert image filter in Java work?

Tags: java, filter

I am trying to write my homework and my code works, the problem is that I don't understand why.
I had to create an image filter in Java, which inverts colors.
Could you explain to me, in simple words what does the following code do? More specifically this line:

```
   int neu = (p) ^ 0x00FFFFFF;
```

Why do I need the "^"?

.....
And the rest, so you could understand what I am trying to do.

```
   public void filterInvert(){
   for(int x = 1; x < w; x++){
    for(int y = 1; y<h; y++){
        int p = filteredImage.getRGB(x, y);
        int neu = (p) ^ 0x00FFFFFF;
        filteredImage.setRGB(x, y, neu); 
    }
}
}
```

Comment: it's the bitwise exclusive OR operator (more about operators [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html)). You've got the 0x00FFFFFF mask (alpha, r, g, b) after the or, so imagine that as your maximum value and after the exlusive OR you get back what's left from your maximum amount. Let's take a simpler example: 0xFF(255) for a grayscale image is your maximum value. If you have a pixel with a value of 32 for example and you want to get the negative of that pixel you would subtract 32 from the maximum(255): 223...

Comment: ...(255 - 32) = 32 ^ 255, but the cool thing is bitwise operations tend to be faster (CPUs love working with bytes generally), but you also don't have to worry about splitting your colours into r,g,b channels, subtracting each channel from 255(max) to get the negative and put the channels back into the hex representation...Simply using ^ against your maximum value deals with this at a binary level in one go. If you have a Calculator application on your computer switch to the Programmer view so you can see what happens to the bytes. HTH